# Facebook and Twitter login stops for few second after login activity android Parse.com

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, parse-platform

I have integrated my application in Parse.com for Facebook and Twitter login.

After login is successful I take user to main screen. However after login from facebook or twitter it comes back to login screen and waits for few seconds before going to main screen. How to avoid wait. Please help.
Following is my twitter and facebook login

```
ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(MyActivity.this, new LogInCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException exception) {
                // my code
                // start new activity on success

            }

        });



ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, MyActivity.this,
                new LogInCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(final ParseUser user,
                            ParseException exception) {
                        // my code
                        // start new activity on success


                    }
                });


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: I was facing the same problem and found a work around. This isnt exactly the solution youre looking for, but what I did was have a "Logging in" progress bar fragment cover my login screen when the user clicked on the facebook login button. This way, when they came back, they were shown this progress bar indicating that log in is being processed.

Comment: i put progress dialog but when facebook login screen comes it vanishes and after coming back to login its vanished already.

Comment: Where did you enable the progress dialog? You should start the progress dialog animation in your `onActivityResult` method. This is the method that is called after the facebook login screens returns back to your app.

Comment: The same applies for Twitter. `onActivityResult` is called everytime your users will return back to your app after completing any third party login methods.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer in case it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem and found a work around. This isnt exactly the solution youre looking for, but what I did was have a "Logging in" progress bar fragment cover my login screen when the user clicked on the facebook login button. This way, when they came back, they were shown this progress bar indicating that log in is being processed.

This progress bar needs to begin animation in the `onActivityResult` method. This method is called every time the users return back to your app after completing the authentication process in any third party login (facebook/twitter/google etc). This progress bar will keep running untill finally your new activity begins.

Comment: should i put progress bar at end of code in onActivityResult or at start

Comment: At the start. I think its the finishAuthentication method that is causing the delay.

Comment: i add that worked i want to instead freeze screen and show progress bar.. what will be good way

Comment: Where do you want to freeze the screen? I think you cannot prevent the Facebook/twitter popup from showing. Those screens cannot be bypassed.